# Match UIStackView's .fill alignment with SwiftUI VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I've got a `VStack` with 3 `Text`s in it. Each has a different length string. I'd like the `VStack`'s width to be just big enough to fit the widest `Text`, but I'd also like all three `Text`s to fill the VStack horizontally.

By default, with this code:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 4.0) {
    ForEach(1..<4) {
        Text(Array<String>(repeating: "word", count: $0).joined(separator: " "))
            .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

I get:

[image: VStack with three different width Texts]

I want:

[image: VStack with three same width Texts]

In UIKit, I could do this with a vertical `UIStackView` whose `alignment` property was set to `.fill`. `VStack` doesn't have a `.fill` alignment. The suggested solution I've seen is to modify the frame of each child of the stack view (ie. each `Text`) with `.infinity` for `maxWidth`.

The suggestion I've found is to modify the `Text`s with `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`. However, this makes the whole `VStack` expand to (presumably) its maximum size:

[image: Wide VStack]

Is there a way to make the `VStack` naturally grow to the size of its widest child, and no larger, while making all its children the same width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `.fixedSize()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack(spacing: 4.0) {
            ForEach(1..<4) {
                Text(Array<String>(repeating: "word", count: $0).joined(separator: " "))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) /// keep the maxWidth
                    .background(Color.gray)
            }
        }
        .fixedSize() /// here!
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 3 Texts with gray background stacked vertically, all 3 gray backgrounds have the largest Text's width]